# Counting records from related tables Gridview

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2

I have 3 tables named `hostgroup`, `host` and `services`.

I have a database like this for example.

```
Hostgroup: 
id, name
1   GroupA
2   GroupB

Host: 
id, name, hostgroup_id
1   HostA       1
2   HostB       1
3   HostC       2
4   HostD       2
5   HostE       2


//2 = critical, 1 = warning
Service: 
id, host_id, state
1     1        2
2     1        2
3     2        1
4     2        1
5     3        2
```

The final table should be like this:

```
Name        Total Hosts          Total Critical       Total Warning
GroupA         2                      2                     2
GroupB         3                      1                     0
```

I was able to do the 2nd column which is `Total Hosts` by adding this function on my `Hostgroup` model:

```
public function getHostcount()
{
    return Host::find()->where(['hostgroup_id' => $this->id])->count();
}
```

How can I count the total warning and critical also?

- Total critical (counts the number of total critical status of hosts related to the hostgroup)
- Total warning (counts the number of total warning status of hosts related to the hostgroup)

EDIT: ADDED SOURCE CODE

**HostgroupSearch** model:

```
<?php
class HostgroupSearch extends Hostgroup
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'check_interval', 'retry_interval', 'max_check_attempts', 'timeout', 'freshness_threshold', 'is_auto_recovery', 'reflect_flg', 'created_user_id'], 'integer'],
            [['object_name', 'name', 'name_search', 'remarks', 'snmp_community', 'timestamp'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Hostgroup::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'check_interval' => $this->check_interval,
            'retry_interval' => $this->retry_interval,
            'max_check_attempts' => $this->max_check_attempts,
            'timeout' => $this->timeout,
            'freshness_threshold' => $this->freshness_threshold,
            'is_auto_recovery' => $this->is_auto_recovery,
            'reflect_flg' => $this->reflect_flg,
            'created_user_id' => $this->created_user_id,
            'timestamp' => $this->timestamp,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'object_name', $this->object_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name_search', $this->name_search])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'remarks', $this->remarks])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'snmp_community', $this->snmp_community]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

This **HostlistController** controls the display of everything in my table.

```
<?
class HostlistController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = "default";

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new HostgroupSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}

?>
```

This is then my view page **index.php**:

```
'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Name',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data, $id) { 
                    return Html::a($data->name, '/index.php/hostlistbygroup/'. $id);
            },
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Total Host',
            'attribute' => 'hostcount',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Total Critical',
            'attribute' => 'host.criticalcount',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Total Warning',
            'attribute' => 'host.warningcount',
        ],
```

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I already tried that actually using on my other gridviews like in the view page of my host, instead of hostgroup_id I displayed its name. Now my problem is about the computation.

Comment: please add the code, a snippet of template and activerecord call

Comment: I do not understand, you want to add three columns or three fields ?. The results you are trying to view are amounts and can not understand why they are in the columns of the gridview. explains better.

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge I added additional infos. I hope everything would be clear now.

Comment: This not asnwer at my question. If you want three columns on three fields with the related total... At me seems you want threere total fields please explain this aspect.

Comment: I wanted to show three columns on gridview where in: 1st column counts the total hosts under that group, 2nd colum counts the total critical on hosts under that group and 3rd column counts the total warning on hosts under that group.

Comment: Ok the sum is group by hostgroup...I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Solved it by adding these functions to `Host` model.

```
public function getCriticalcount()
{
    return ServiceStatuses::find()->where(['host_id' => $this->id, 'last_hard_state' => '2'])->count();
}

public function getWarningcount()
{
    return ServiceStatuses::find()->where(['host_id' => $this->id, 'last_hard_state' => '1'])->count();
}
```

and added this to `Hostgroup` model

```
public function getHost()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Host::className(), ['hostgroup_id' => 'id']);
}
```

modified index.php with this

```
 'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Name',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data, $id) { 
                    return Html::a($data->name, '/index.php/hostlistbygroup/'. $id);
            },
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Total Host',
            'attribute' => 'hostcount',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Total Critical',
            'attribute' => 'host.criticalcount',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Total Warning',
            'attribute' => 'host.warningcount',
        ],
```